# Excel VBA Runtime 3704 Operation is not allowed when object is closed

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, stored-procedures

I have been using this code for some time and it works.  As a matter of fact it works with a basic query.  It just does not work with my new Stored Procedure.  I can run the stored procedure manually.  in SSMS and get my results.  I thought that the error was when I was not getting data back so I added the . . . If myRS1.EOF Then  . . . still getting the 3704 runtime error.

Here is my Excel (2013) Code

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

Dim myStartDate, myEndDate
Dim myInsuranceCode
Dim objAD, objUser
Dim myDisplayName, myLastRow
Dim myMessage, myStyle, myTitle, myResult
Dim mySQL As String
Dim myConn 
Dim myCmd 
Dim myRS1 
Dim myRange, myNamedRange, myCheckRange As Range
Dim X, Y, z
Dim myPercent, myLowEnd, myHighEnd
Dim myValue1, myValue2, myValue3, myValue4, myValue5, myValue6, myValue7, myValue8
Dim myCheckValue

Dim myHeaderRow, myDataRow, myLastColumn

'SET THESE ACCORDING TO THE REPORT.  THE FIRST TWO MIGHT NOT NEED ANY CHANGES
    myHeaderRow = 2
    myDataRow = 3
    myLastColumn = 22

'SETUP DATABASE OBJECTS
    Set myConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set myCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set myRS1 = New ADODB.Recordset
    
    Application.StatusBar = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Connecting to SQL Server"

'GET DATES FROM TEH FORM AND SET SQL STATEMENT
    myStartDate = frmMain.txtStartDate
    myEndDate = frmMain.txtEndDate
    
    'RUN INSURANCE STORE PROCEDURE
    'SEPERATE THE INSURANCE CODE WITH A |
    myInsuranceCode = "S19|S22"
    mySQL = "dbo.BMH_rpt_PATIENTS_INSURANCE_LISTING '" & myStartDate & "', '" & myEndDate & "', '" & myInsuranceCode & "'"
    'mySQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.BETHESDA_ADMIT_SOURCE"
        
'HIDE THE FORM
    frmMain.Hide

'GET THE USER THAT IS SIGNED IN
    Set objAD = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & objAD.UserName)
    myDisplayName = objUser.DisplayName

'OPEN CONNECTIONS TO THE DATABASE
    myConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=mySQLServer;Initial Catalog=myDatabaseName;User ID=user;Password=xxxxxxxx;Connection Timeout=300;"
    myConn.Open

'SET AND EXECUTE SQL COMMAND
    Set myCmd.ActiveConnection = myConn
    myCmd.CommandText = mySQL
    myCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    Application.StatusBar = "Running Stored Procedure " & mySQL
    myCmd.CommandTimeout = 3000
'OPEN RECORDSET
    Set myRS1.Source = myCmd
    myRS1.Open
       
'CHECK TO MAKE SURE WE ARE NOT AT THE BOTTOM OF THE SHEET COULD MEAN THERE WAS NOT DATA LAST TIME.
'THIS SAME CODE WILL REPEAT FOR THE DATA TAB
'*********** DATA *************
'CHECK TO MAKE SURE THERE IS DATA
    If myRS1.EOF Then  <---- THIS IS THE LINE I AM GETTING THE ERROR
       
        Cells(myDataRow, 1).Value = "No Data Qualifies"
           myMessage = "No data qualifing for your request " & mySQL
           myTitle = "No Data"
           myStyle = vbCritical + vbOKOnly
                myResult = MsgBox(myMessage, myStyle, myTitle)
                     Exit Sub
    End If

'SELECT THE SHEET TO CLEAR OUT THE OLD data on DATA
'IF THIS IS NOT SET ON THE SEEHET IT WILL FAIL
    Set myTable = Sheets("DATA").ListObjects("DATA")
    If Cells(myDataRow, 1).Value <> "" Then
        myTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
    End If

'COPY THE DATA TO EXCEL
    Application.StatusBar = "Copying the new data."
    Sheets("DATA").Cells(myDataRow, 1).CopyFromRecordset myRS1
    Cells(1048576, 1).Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select

    myLastRow = ActiveCell.Row

    'Application.StatusBar = "Naming the new DATA range"

    'ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=myNamedRange, RefersTo:=Range(Cells(myHeaderRow, 1), Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn))

    myTable.Resize Range(Cells(myHeaderRow, 1), Cells(myLastRow, myLastColumn))

End Sub
```

*** This is all the VBA Code now.  It is failing on the myRS1.EOF line so none of the other code even runs.

As you can see I have two mySQL statements.  The first one is not working, but the second one works no issue.

If I run the SP from SSMS or even take the mySQL that is generated it runs fine in SSMS.

Here is the SP

```
--EXAMPLE
--            dbo.BMH_rpt_PATIENTS_INSURANCE_LISTING '11/01/2020', '11/30/2020', 'S19|S22'

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BMH_rpt_PATIENTS_INSURANCE_LISTING]
              @StartDate           AS     DATETIME,
              @EndDate             AS     DATETIME,
              @Insurance           AS     VARCHAR(MAX)
AS

/**  GET THE INSURANCE CODES  **/

SELECT        VALUE
INTO          #INSURANCE   
FROM          STRING_SPLIT(@Insurance, '|')
  
/**  GET THE PATIENTS FOR THE LIST  **/
SELECT        vv.pt_id AS 'Patient Account',
              vv.alt_med_rec_no AS 'MRN'
FROM          smsdss.vst_v AS vv 
WHERE         vv.pyr_cd IN (SELECT * FROM #INSURANCE)
              AND vv.start_full_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
              AND vv.tot_bal_amt <> 0
```

Comment: Rest of the code please

Comment: Added the reset of the VBA code.  It fails on the myRS1.EOF and the rest of the code does not even run.

Comment: Try parameterizing the command. You anyway should because of SQL injection

Comment: Add `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the proc code.

Comment: You can check the state of the recordset to see if it's open or not using `If  myRS1.State = adStateOpen`   Also you can check the Errors property of the connection object to see if your call generated any errors  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/provider-errors?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you all for you help I have tried each of your suggestions but it still is not working.  I am still getting the error that the object is closed.  I checked the state right after I try and  open it still it is a 0.  I then moved to the Stored Procedure.  It seems if I remove
    SELECT        VALUE
INTO          #INSURANCE   FROM          
STRING_SPLIT(@Insurance, '|') 
it works fine.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I found that it was just easier to remove the insert into the temp table in my Stored Procedure and instead create a table and insert the values into he table and then use that table as criteria for my main table.